# asyncio cleanup when getting system signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a monitor which is running forever within event loop and I want to properly close it when receiving sigint signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
Consider the following example

```
class Scheduler(object):
    def __init__(self, tasks=None, interval=1):
        self.tasks = tasks or []
        self.interval = interval

    async def run_forever(self):
        while True:
            await self.run_once()
            print('Waiting %s seconds to make next update...' %
                  self.interval)
            await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)

    async def run_once(self):
        await asyncio.gather(*self.tasks)

    async def cleanup(self):
        print('Cleaning up resources...')


async def run(scheduler):
    try:
        await scheduler.run_forever()
    finally:
        await scheduler.cleanup()

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    scheduler = Scheduler()
    loop.run_until_complete(run(scheduler))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But it doesn't call cleanup function in finally clause

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
Waiting 1 seconds to make next update...
Waiting 1 seconds to make next update...
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "shce.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "shce.py", line 50, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(run(scheduler))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 454, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1395, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 445, in select
    fd_event_list = self._epoll.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

But the code below works properly

```
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    scheduler = Scheduler()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(scheduler.run_forever())
    except KeyboardInerrupt:
        print('Soo god')
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(scheduler.cleanup())
```

What is missing in the first code sample that it does not want to call a cleanup code and how does it differ from the second one?

Comment: This question would better fit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Both snippets are equal and do the same job.

The second looks a little more elegant from my perspective.

Comment: thanks, but check the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49908223/1744914